# I have 4 points and need to find the distance between two of them

Tags: geometry

Assume you are given 4 points in an xy coordinate system. You know the distance between every set of points except two. You are not given the coordinates of the points. Is there a general formula for finding the last distance. My approach was to make one of the points from the set of points without specified distances a random point and to make the rest of the points as part of a triangle. With this, you can use the law of cosine and other triangles to derive the last side. However, you run into different scenarios and have to differentiate them by eye. I do not want to have to classify these scenarios.

Comment: Frankly I don't understand what you are asking.  If you have the coordinates of the points, say $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ then the distance between them is $\sqrt{(x_1- x_2)^2+ (y_1- y_2)^2+ (z_1- z_2)^2}$.  Apparently you are not given that.  So what **are** you given?  **How** did calculate the other distances?  What does the "cosine law" have to do with this?

Comment: sorry for the confusing question, I updated the question

Comment: what if they were not in a plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Cayley-Menger determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant) for volume of a tetrahedron. With the four vertices in a plane, the volume is zero and this gives a quadratic equation in the square of a distance. Also the same
thing in the Wikipedia article [Quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral) on "other metric relations".